# Gson with Kotlin nested class

Tags: gson, deserialization, kotlin

I fail to properly deserialize a nested Kotlin class as the correct type with Gson.
When I try to deserialize the same Java class, it works fine.

Java Class:

```
package example;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class TestJsonJava {
    Map<String, List<Entry>> outer;

    static class Entry {
        String inner;
    }
}
```

Kotlin class:

```
package example

class TestJsonKotlin {
    var outer: Map<String, List<Entry>>? = null

    class Entry {
        var inner: String? = null
    }
}
```

Kotlin main:

```
package example

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder

class Main {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            val json = """
{
    "outer": {
        "keyA": [
            {
                "inner": "hello"
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""
            val javaObject = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, TestJsonJava::class.java)
            val javaWorks = javaObject.outer!!["keyA"]!![0] is TestJsonJava.Entry
            println("Java works  : $javaWorks")
            println(javaObject.outer!!["keyA"]!![0].inner)

            val kotlinObject = GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, TestJsonKotlin::class.java)
            val kotlinWorks = kotlinObject.outer!!["keyA"]!![0] is TestJsonKotlin.Entry
            println("Kotlin works: $kotlinWorks")
            println(kotlinObject.outer!!["keyA"]!![0].inner)
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
Java works  : true
hello
Kotlin works: false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to example.TestJsonKotlin$Entry
    at example.Main$Companion.main(TestJsonmain.kt:28)
    at example.Main.main(TestJsonmain.kt)
```

How do I tell gson to deserialize the value of `keyA` to a `List<Entry>` instead of `LinkedTreeMap`?

Comment: I noticed [you're yelling a lot at the compiler.](https://blog.philipphauer.de/idiomatic-kotlin-best-practices/#avoid-not-null-assertions) I assume this use of `!!` is just for MCVE purposes?

Comment: yep, this is just for the example to keep things simple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotating the `List` with `@JvmSuppressWildcards` seems to help:

```
var outer: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards List<Entry>>? = null
```

---

If we don't use `@JvmSuppressWildcards`, then the Kotlin code is translated to:

```
Map<String, ? extends List<TestJsonKotlin.Entry>> outer;
```

If we do use it, then the code is translated to:

```
Map<String, List<TestJsonKotlin.Entry>> outer;
```

The difference is in the wildcard `? extends` – this is not supported even if you write this in Java. I have filed an issue in Gson's repository [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1101).

---

The `javap` highlights the difference between the two cases:

```
// `TestJsonKotlin` with `val outer` is compiled to
public final class TestJsonKotlin {
  private final java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<TestJsonKotlin$Entry>> outer;
  public final java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<TestJsonKotlin$Entry>> getOuter();
  // ...
}

// `TestJsonKotlin` with `var outer` is compiled to
public final class TestJsonKotlin {
  private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ? extends java.util.List<TestJsonKotlin$Entry>> outer;
  public final java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<TestJsonKotlin$Entry>> getOuter();
  // ...
}
```

The `var` case adds `? extends` in front of the `java.util.List<TestJsonKotlin$Entry>`.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Gson issue, and it really sounds like `kotlinc` (does it exist?) does not produce parameterization information for `var outer`. What does `javap` output for both cases, `var` and `val`?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. It would be nice to get the Gson team feedback. Thank you!

Comment: `@JvmSuppressWildcards` seems to help

Comment: Good finding. I would like the `javap` output to remain in your answer in order to highlight the investigation process -- this would explain why that annotation works.